# Why doesn't Peterson's algorithm require mutual exclusion at the memory access level?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, mutual-exclusion

In Stallings's "Operating Systems", chapter 5, there is the following problem:

> Demonstrate that the following software approaches to mutual exclusion
>   do not depend on elementary mutual exclusion at the memory access
>   level:
>
> [..]
>
> b. Peterson's algorithm.

Here is Peterson's algorithm in pseudocode, from the book:

```
boolean flag[2];
int turn;
void P0()
{
    while (true) {
        flag [0] = true;
        turn = 1;
        while (flag [1] && turn == 1) /* do nothing */;
        /* critical section */;
        flag [0] = false;
        /* remainder */;
    }
}
void P1()
{
    while (true) {
        flag [1] = true;
        turn = 0;
        while (flag [0] && turn == 0) /* do nothing */;
        /* critical section */;
        flag [1] = false;
        /* remainder */
    }
}
void main()
{
    flag [0] = false;
    flag [1] = false;
    parbegin (P0, P1);
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding how is it possible to assume that there is no mutual exclusion at the memory access level.

For example: If we don't assume that the writes `turn = 0` and `turn = 1` are atomic, then it seems to me that having them run concurrently (or in parallel) could hypothetically result in `turn` containing garbage.

Also, if, for example, P0 runs `flag[0] = true` at the same time that P1 reads from `flag[0]`, without atomicity, it seems to me that P1 could read garbage.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have to check the basic assumptions of the book: if a variable is written by multiple threads, is it possible to observe any value other than the values written to it or its original value? Are threads allowed to reorder memory writes? The algorithm works under certain assumptions.

Comment: The phrase "mutual exclusion at the memory access level" is ambiguous.  P1 couldn't read garbage; it could read either true(1) or false(0).  It couldn't read, for example, 42.   Memory reads & writes within alignment constraints are atomic; you do not read partial updates.  Whether it reads a 1 or a 0 is not deterministic, since  memory access is not synchronized.